# JuMP - MethodError: `getindex` has no method matching getindex(::Function, ::Int64)

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I have to calculate the ideal vector of this multiobjective problem. I cannot how to access the first and second function of the functs_BK1() in the @objective. 
Any Idea how I could make all dynamic and support n-functions?

```
using JuMP
using Ipopt


function functs_BK1(x::Vector)
    f = zeros(2)
    f[1] = x[1]^2 + x[2]^2
    f[2] = (x[1]-5.0)^2 + (x[2]-5.0)^2

    return f
end

function bounds_BK1()
    return ([-5.0;-5.0],[10.0;10.0])
end


m = Model(solver=IpoptSolver(print_level=0))
@variable(m, x[i=1:2])

@NLexpression(m, F1, functs_BK1()[1]) #<--- Problem is here
@NLexpression(m, F2, functs_BK1()[2]) #<--- here

@constraint(m, x .>= bounds_BK1()[1])
@constraint(m, x .<= bounds_BK1()[2])
s=solve(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function `functs_BK1`, you have defined `f` to be an array of `Float64` values, while the `@NLexpression` macro must build up the desired expression from JuMP variables as its third argument.  As stated in the [JuMP documentation for Nonlinear Expressions](http://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nlp.html#syntax-notes), all nonlinear expressions must be defined inside of the `@NLexpression` macro, and `AffExpr` and `QuadExpr` objects cannot currently be used inside of the `@NLexpression` macro.

The following set of commands results in finding a solution via the `solve` operation:

```
julia> using JuMP

julia> using Ipopt

julia> m = Model(solver=IpoptSolver(print_level=0))
Feasibility problem with:
 * 0 linear constraints
 * 0 variables
Solver is Ipopt

julia> @variable(m, x[i=1:2])
2-element Array{JuMP.Variable,1}:
 x[1]
 x[2]

julia> function bounds_BK1()
           return ([-5.0;-5.0],[10.0;10.0])
       end
bounds_BK1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @NLexpression(m, F1, x[1]^2 + x[2]^2)
JuMP.NonlinearExpression(Feasibility problem with:
 * 0 linear constraints
 * 2 variables
Solver is Ipopt,1)

julia> @NLexpression(m, F2, (x[1]-5.0)^2 + (x[2]-5.0)^2)
JuMP.NonlinearExpression(Feasibility problem with:
 * 0 linear constraints
 * 2 variables
Solver is Ipopt,2)

julia> @constraint(m, x .>= bounds_BK1()[1])
2-element Array{JuMP.ConstraintRef{JuMP.Model,JuMP.GenericRangeConstraint{JuMP.GenericAffExpr{Float64,JuMP.Variable}}},1}:
 x[1] ≥ -5
 x[2] ≥ -5

julia> @constraint(m, x .<= bounds_BK1()[2])
2-element Array{JuMP.ConstraintRef{JuMP.Model,JuMP.GenericRangeConstraint{JuMP.GenericAffExpr{Float64,JuMP.Variable}}},1}:
 x[1] ≤ 10
 x[2] ≤ 10

julia> s = solve(m)

******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
         For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
******************************************************************************

:Optimal

julia> getvalue(x)
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.261454
 0.261454
```

I do not believe that it is currently possible for you to build up an array of expressions within your `functs_BK1` that would later be passed to `@NLexpression`.  At present, one needs to pass the scalar expressions of JuMP variables directly in as arguments to `@NLexpression`.